# How to test a android project which includes edittext ,button and listview?

Tags: android, listview, testing, android-listview, android-edittext

I did develop an android project which includes edittext , button and listview . I have a mainActivity which includes these views in it's layout.When user enter a text on Edittext and clikc the buttom ,text will transfer to listview.Up to here, everything is okey , I can do that.Addition to this,I did create class which is extended by ArrayAdapter because I want to optimize application.I want to test application with 1000 text etc ,thanks to this I can optimize my adapter, but I don not know how to I test it ?

```
public class TodoItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TodoItem> {
int resource;
public TodoItemAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<TodoItem> objects) {
    super(context, resource ,objects);
    this.resource = resource ;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TodoItem toDoItem = getItem(position);
    String toDoTask = toDoItem.task;
    String toDoDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(toDoItem.enteringData );

    String inflaterService = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(inflaterService);

    View toDoView = inflater.inflate(this.resource,null);
    TextView taskView = (TextView) toDoView.findViewById(R.id.tvTask);
    TextView dateView = (TextView) toDoView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);

    taskView.setText(toDoTask);
    dateView.setText(toDoDate);

    return  toDoView;
}
```

}

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private ArrayList <TodoItem> todoItems;
private TodoItemAdapter  todoArrayAdapter ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    final EditText etTodo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTodo);
    Button btnAddTodo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddTodo);
    ListView lvTodoItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.todoListView);
    todoItems = new ArrayList<TodoItem>();// line1
    todoArrayAdapter = new TodoItemAdapter(this,R.layout.todoitem,todoItems) ;//line2
    lvTodoItems.setAdapter(todoArrayAdapter); //line3
    //line1,line2 and line3 apply ( DataSource -> Adapter -> AdapterView ) schema.

    btnAddTodo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            todoItems.add(new TodoItem(etTodo.getText().toString()));
            todoArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            etTodo.setText("");
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: I did test my project with a simple for loop with **for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++){String test = "testing";todoItems.add(new TodoItem(test));}todoArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit) to write Android UI tests like the following:

```
public void testAdapter() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
     onView(withId(R.id.etTodo))
       .perform(typeText("Todo #" + i));
     onView(withId(R.id.btnAddTodo))
       .perform(click());
  }
}
```